# Python : CGI application not receiving CGI variables with special characters

Tags: python, html

I am having a HTML web page that POST's a AJAX call to a Python script:

```
/proxy/filter.py?action=ADD&value=+/sdsd/+&option=URL
/proxy/filter.py?action=ADD&value=-/sdsd/-&option=URL
```

In my Python script I am extracting the CGI variables via below method:

```
value = form['value'].value
option = form['option'].value
```

The issue with the code is that where ever there is a '+' sign (no issues with '-') I am not receiving it (as within the CGI variables value). When I print the value in the Web Page I see it correctly.

Is it a issue with how I am posting the data or with my Python code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside URLs, `+` is converted automatically to spaces. You need to escape it in your AJAX call:

```
/proxy/filter.py?action=ADD&value=%2B/sdsd/&2B&option=URL
```

You can do that automatically with the JS `encodeURIComponent()` function.

Comment: Can you please let me know how can I do that?

Comment: Thanks - but then my POST itself is failing - The URL gets changes to %2Fproxy%2Flogin.py%3Fusername%3Dadmin%26password%3Dadmin for /proxy/login.py?username=admin&password=admin

Comment: You should only be encoding the query values, not the whole URL.